# Falling out with the Judge

Tags: word, wordplay, cryptic-clues

> Poor defense speech leading to defendant finally being thrown out (14)

The defendant never reached their prison cell. How did they die?

<sub>[jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe) helped design the clue - thanks! :)</sub>

Comment: Is this a correct characterization of the clue? Nqwrpgvir abha nqwhapg abha cerfrag cebterffvir cercbfvgvba abha nqireo cerfrag cebterffvir cnfg cnegvpvcyr cercbfvgvba

Comment: @Acccumulation I don't think so, but anyhow I don't want to reveal much in that direction, as it could accidentally spoil the clue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like:

> **DEFENESTRATION**

Because:

> poor = anagram of [ defense + speech + (leading) to] : **DEFENSE** + **ORATION** + **T** => **DEFENESTORATION**

But I am slightly confused by:

> I need to remove **O**... is this **O** for offender? (as a defendant being thrown out?)

EDIT 2:

> I'm not sure I have another path forward other than finding a word that means "defendant" that ends in **-O**.

EDIT 3:

> Thanks to Stiv the light dawns and the last step is to *exchange* the leading letter of "speech" (ORATION) with the final letter of "defendant" (T) and now I can finally sleep.

But the total is:

> Being thrown out a window!

Comment: You're almost there, just a little fiddling left with the WP :)

Comment: I think you need to rot13(punatr gur 'yrnqvat' punenpgre bs BENGVBA 'gb' qrsraqnaG svanyyl - v.r. punatr gur B gb n G) - that then uses all the words in the clue :)

Comment: @Stiv ... thank you ... that makes far more sense.  I even wrote that in my scrapped edit #42.